# jqgrid change search parameter in colmodel dynamiclly

Tags: jqgrid

I have a nav button added by myself. when click it I use:

```
$("#"+gridId).setColProp('myColumn', { search: true });
```

But I find that once I click the search button, the columns that can or can't be searched is defined and not change with the `setColProp` method.
How can I dynamically change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `recreateFilter` property which default value is `false` like the value of [recreateForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property. In my opinion the default value of the properties should be `true` (see [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/change-default-settings-for-recreatefilter-and-recreateform-to-true/#p21082)).

In any way to solve the problem you can just include

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {recreateFilter: true});
```

in your code. It will change the default value of `recreateFilter`. How you can verify on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchPropertyDynamically.htm) the problem will be solved after that.